# Associating New products with the Current User in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Currently If i try adding a new product , i get this error IntegrityError "NOT NULL constraint failed: products.merchant_id"
what i want to achieve is product to be associated with the current user.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   merchant=models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class Merchant(models.Model):
   user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```
def addproduct(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_product=form.save(commit=False)
            new_product.merchant__user=request.user
            new_product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('users:users_homepage')
    else:
        form=ProductForm()
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'users/addproduct.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, you haven't created a `Merchant` object to go with your `Product`. And so you can't assign a user to a merchant that doesn't exist yet. You need to do something like this:

```
...
        if form.is_valid():
            new_product=form.save(commit=False)
            merchant, _ = Merchant.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            new_product.merchant = merchant
            new_product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('users:users_homepage')
```

FYI: The double underscore notation you are using is for querying models, you can't use it just as an equivalent to chained properties.

I suppose there's a chance you are creating a merchant instance in your ProductForm save method. If you've done this, then you'd simply need to do:

```
merchant = new_product.merchant
merchant.user = request.user
merchant.save()
```

Comment: error again "Cannot assign "(<Merchant: aliyu>, False)": "Product.merchant" must be a "Merchant" instance"

Comment: @mustapha ah, sorry. get_or_create returns a tuple. I have updated my answer (the line with get_or_create on). It should work correctly now.